# Microsoft nmake: Is it possible to define macros from shell command output?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nmake

I am trying to save my SVN revision info into a macro while making my code by Microsoft Visual Studio's nmake.

In GNU make, I do something like:

```
SVN_REVISION=r$(shell svnversion -n)
```

so I get for example: SVN_REVISION=r10001

Is this possible to do in Microsoft nmake too?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "NMAKE inherits macro definitions for environment variables that exist before the start of the session". And so you can simply define that before invoking `nmake`. One way to define it programmatically is via a `for /f "usebackq"`, and another way is possibly via a `set /p`. I haven't tried. Check it out.

Comment: @Alf Thank you for your reply. Yes, the way you mentioned is my current solution. I was wondering if I can do it in one Makefile when defining Macros. I tried things like this:`for /f %%i in ('svnversion -n') do set revision=r%%i`, but it did not work well in makefile somehow :/

Comment: Well you need the `"usebackq"` option also. Double percent signs in batch file, single percent signs for interactive command. Isn't it wonderful. :-D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the techniques mentioned along with a recursive call to make, it can be done this way:

```
!IFNDEF MAKE
MAKE=NMAKE
!ENDIF
!IFNDEF SVN_REVISION
!   IF [echo off && FOR /F "usebackq" %i IN (`svnrevision -n`) DO  SET SVN_REVISION=%i && $(MAKE)      /$(MAKEFLAGS) /nologo /f $(MAKEDIR)\Makefile && exit /b  ] == 0
!     MESSAGE Make completed
!   ELSE
!     ERROR Error in nmake
!   ENDIF
!ELSE
# $(SVN_REVISION) now contains the string returned from the command `svnrevision -n`
!MESSAGE SVN_REVISION is $(SVN_REVISION)
#      Put the parts of the makefile that depend on SVN_REVISION here
!ENDIF
#
# To be a valid makefile it must have some rules to perform
all:
     @echo;$(SVN_REVISION)
```

Comment: You are smart, while nmake is not.